# The Jungo WinDriver need a linux symbolic link , what does it mean?

Tags: linux, usb, driver

Its manual says:

> To run GUI WinDriver applications (e.g., DriverWizard [5]; Debug Monitor [7.2]) you must also
> have version 5.0 of the libstdc++ library — libstdc++.so.5. If you do not have this file, install it from the relevant RPM in your Linux distribution (e.g., compat-libstdc++).
>
> Before proceeding with the installation, you must also make sure that you have a linux symbolic link. If you do not, create one by typing : /usr/src$ ln -s 'target kernel'/linux
>
> For example, for the Linux 2.4 kernel type :
>
> /usr/src$ ln -s linux-2.4/ linux

what does this `symbolic link` mean ?  what do the `<target kernel>` and `linux` preset ?

If I install WinDriver in Ubuntu 13.10 , how should specify these two parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

When installing WinDriver on a Linux machine, you must make sure that you are compiling WinDriver with the same header files that were used to build your kernel. `#uname -a` will tell you your kernel version number.

You should verify that the directory /usr/src/linux (normally a symbolic ink) is pointing to the correct kernel header sources and that the header files are using exactly the same version numbers as your running kernel.
A  refers to the location of the kernel headers and  refers to the Linux kernel name-number.

```
To fix this:
Become super user: $su ;
Change directory to: /usr/src/: # cd /usr/src/ ;
Delete the previous link you created (if any): # rm linux ;
And create a new symbolic: #  ln -s linux-2.4/ linux.
```

I recommend following the Linux installation procedure from the Windriver manual at:
http://www.jungo.com/st/support/documentation/windriver/11.5.0/wdpci_manual.mhtml/wd_install_process.html#wd_install_linux

Regards,
Nadav, Jungo support manager

Comment: But how can I specify the 'target kernel' in my ubuntu ?

Comment: Double check that you have the kernel headers installed on your ubuntu machine, verify the kernel name with the command #uname -a use as the string that replaces the 'target kernel'
Regards,
Nadav, Jungo connectivity support manager